# Can you "undo" a powerset of an infinite set?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

So for instance, if you take the Beth numbers as a sequence of infinite cardinal numbers:

$\beth_0=\aleph_0$,

$\beth_1=\mathcal{P}(\beth_0)$,

$\beth_2=\mathcal{P}(\beth_1)$,

etc., where $\beth_{\alpha+1}=2^{\beth_\alpha}$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beth_number). I was wondering if you can "undo" a powerset by taking the $\log_2$ of the set. Therefore, we could see that, for example, $\log_2(\beth_1)=\beth_0$, since $\beth_1=2^{\beth_0}$. (Since $\log_2x$ "undoes" $2^x$). However, if we try to apply this to $\beth_0$ (which is equal to $\aleph_0$), by taking $\log_2(\beth_0)$ we should get some cardinal number $\beta$, such that $2^\beta=\beth_0$.

However, this poses a seeming paradox: if $\beta$ is *finite*, then that means we can take $2$ to the power of some finite number to get an infinite number, which we know cannot be true. Therefore, $\beta$ has to be infinite--but what infinite cardinal is it? It can't be larger than $\beth_0$, so it must be $\beth_0$? But this implies that $\log_2(\beth_0)=\beth_0$, and this further implies that $2^{\beth_0}=\beth_0$. But we know that by definition, $2^{\beth_0}=\beth_1$. So, how does this work? I'm stuck and I'm sure that I'm just overlooking something simple but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: If you don't care about cardinals, note that for any given set, $\bigcup \mathcal P x = x$.

Comment: So maybe the union operation satisfies *some* of your requirements. But note that $\mathcal P \bigcup x \ne x$ in general.

Comment: Now, I am absolutely sure that this is a duplicate. I remember answering at least one question of this flavour. But I can't find it right now.

Comment: Not all numbers have logarithms (e.g. log 0 is undefined), so why should all cardinals? Perhaps it's even more obvious that not all cardinals have a log_2 (as you've defined it) by considering finite cardinals; there is no set X such that |PX| = 3, so the finite cardinal number 3 has no logarithm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The boring answer is just that it doesn't make sense to talk about the "$\log_2$" of an infinite cardinal.

One problem is the one you discovered: some cardinals, like $\aleph_0$, are not equal to $2^\kappa$ for any cardinal $\kappa$. So there's no obvious way to define the logarithm of such a cardinal. To put it another way, the exponential function $\kappa\mapsto 2^\kappa$ is not surjective on infinite cardinals.

Even worse, it's consistent with ZFC that the exponential function fails to be *injective* on infinite cardinals. For example, we could have $2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1}$. What should $\log_2$ of this cardinal be?

Comment: Adding to this, let me mention the best "logarithm-analogue" that we can whip up in the cardinals: $l(\kappa)=\min\{\lambda: 2^\lambda\ge\kappa\}$. This is total, agrees with the logarithm when $\kappa$ is a finite power of $2$, and has $l(\mathfrak{c})=\aleph_0$ even if $\mathfrak{c}=2^{\aleph_1}$.